# To draw the synthesis?

Tags: verbs

Can I draw a (or the) synthesis of something? (In a dialectical sense.) What would be alternatives if I wanted to use synthesis?

Comment: _Synthesis_ is the noun form of _synthesize_ 'put things together to make something', and the opposite of _analysis/analyze_ 'take things apart to see how they fit together'. I have no idea why you would want to use _synthesis_ with a dummy verb, when there is a verb already made. Of course, if you use _synthesize_, you have to describe what you have put together and what they now make up; _synthesis_ does not give much information about what it is you're talking about. Perhaps that's what you need, perhaps not.

Comment: No, can you explain what your intended meaning is?

Comment: I'm preparing a presentation for someone who is going to give a talk about her experiences on the two sides of a transaction. She wants to use the (sub-)title 'A Synthesis of both Worlds'. It is meant in the sense of drawing the conclusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's suggested ***draw*** is at least "acceptable" (you can, after all, *draw the threads of an argument together*, and there are many "looser" expressions, such as *drawing conclusions, inferences, etc.*).

But for OP's context, it seems to me a more appropriate verb might be...

> [***assemble*** a synthesis](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Christ%20on%20a%20cross%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22assemble%20a%20synthesis%22&tbm=bks) (or [***construct***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Christ%20on%20a%20cross%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22construct%20a%20synthesis%22&tbm=bks))

I say that because despite the implications of *drawing together* in my first example, ***draw*** in such constructions really has more the sense of *extract* (what is already there). But I'm inclined to think that a "synthesis" isn't really "there" until you create it.